# Audio support for Realtek Chip

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, realtek, asus

I've build my own PC with [ASUS Z97-P](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z97P/specifications/) Motherboard with a Realtek Audio Chip. Everything works fine, but I can't get the audio working. I'm using KDE 5 and tried Phonon with VLC and GStreamer backend, but neither of the two is working. I've also installed Skype, which is using PulseAudio, which is not working as well. (I'm using Arch Linux with the latest 4.1 kernel)

```
$ cat '/proc/asound/card0/codec#0' | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
```

Do I need to install a driver or is there any other trick to get my audio working? I didn't find anything useful on the Asus and Realtek websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here: http://www.debianuserforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=2433#p23869

I just had to enter

```
modprobe snd_hda_codec
modprobe snd_hda_intel
modprobe snd_hda_intel_codec
```

and now the sound is working